# Is the Unity Framework any good for Inversion of Control?

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have been using [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) for a little while now and I am curious if I should use Microsoft's [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203101.aspx) framework (official name "Unity Application Block").  Does anyone have experience using it?  So for I have been copying my IoC container code from project to project, but I think it would be better to using something standard.  I think IoC can make a HUGE difference in keeping component based applications loosely coupled and therefore changeable but I am by no means an expert on IoC, so I am nervous to switch to a framework that will just paint me into a corner as a dependency I will one day want to walk away from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say stick with the one you know until you feel confident with it and the whole concept. After what you'll have a better judgement to pick a framework which fullfill your needs.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Unity with no real problems. I know a few ALT.NET type people warn against Unity but I really think that is just because of the history the MS P&P team have of writing bloatware. Unity is not yet bloated IMO and works well.

Answer (score 5):

I took a look at the Unity Framework, but found it to be a little 'too big' for my needs (no, I can't really quantify that, it just seemed to require much more knowledge that other frameworks that I've been playing with... this was a while ago so it's possible that that's changed as Unity's been developed/refined).

My current IoC/Dependency Injection framework is [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org). It's quick, fast, and I was able to go from reading the tutorials (about 10 minutes) to using it in a pre-existing project in about two hours.

If you're looking for a clean way to do dependency injection, I'd highly recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 3):

I've played with CompositeWPF (aka Prism) - successor of Composite app block. From my experience Unity works much better as compared with previous version of ObjectBuilder. However it's up to you to evaluate IoC frameworks and choose one suited for your needs.

[Unity tutorials & samples](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Category/Unity.aspx)

[Unity IoC Screencast](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2008/02/22/unity-ioc-screencast.aspx)